# Buck converter is stuck at a certain voltage?

Tags: converter

We are currently building a buck converter (see below).
[image]

**Values of components:**
Capacitor: 15 micro Farad
Inductor: 1.41 milli Henry
Mosfet: N-mosfet
Resistor: 330 ohm

**Problem:**

When applying a 15 volt and up the output voltage does not change anymore. The output voltage sticks at 5.6 volt and won't go up anymore. Every component has been replaced (including another voltage supply and voltage meter). Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Instead of a theoretical schematic, provide the actual schematic of the circuit you have built. Without knowing how you are switching and what's driving the switch, we cannot answer this.

Comment: ^ this. you provide a resistor value, but there's no resistor in the schematic. the mosfet driving circuit might be the culript but there's no way to guess the answer if you don't ask a proper question. -1 until you edit.

Comment: @VladimirCravero I would imagine the resistor is the load. Nonetheless - you are correct in that the actual schematic is needed.

Comment: yep, I imagine the resistor is the load, too. but what if the resistor is between L and C to make a low pass filter? A loadless buck can't work anyway, not in the way I suspect OP is driving it.

Answer (score 1):

Without a detailed schematic, it's extremely hard to answer this question.

However, one hint is that you mention using an N[-channel] MOSFET, presumably as your switching element, with the source connected to the diode and inductor.

Keep in mind that the MOSFET source terminal voltage cannot go higher than the gate voltage minus the threshold voltage of the MOSFET. For example, if the gate is being driven by 10V and the threshold voltage is 4.4V, the source cannot go any higher than 10V - 4.4V = 5.6V.

When using an N-channel device as a high-side switch, you need to use a gate driver that can drive the gate well above the drain voltage. In switching power supplies, this is usually implemented using a "bootstrap" circuit.